# Show Loading image Until div fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load

I'm trying to show a loading image until a div content is fully loaded.

1. First hide `.main-slider div`
2. Add class `.loading` to `.main-slider`: `<div id="main-slider loading"></div>`
3. When `.main-slider div` elements has loaded
4. `.loading` will be remove
5. Then fade in `.main-slider div`

html

```
 <div class='sly-main-slider'>
 <div> <!-- Content -->
 <img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-gk6rnMRH9qE/VXJ40BWuC4I/AAAAAAAABZs/BWesiVwBgfg/s1050/camera-girl-nikon-photography-Favim.com-205093.jpg"/>
 </div>
 </div> <!--sly-main-slider end-->
```

jquery tries, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/och42noo/):

```
// when user browses to page
$(".sly-main-slider div").hide();
$(".sly-main-slider").addClass("loading");

$(".sly-main-slider div").load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
  $(".sly-main-slider div").show();
  $(".sly-main-slider").removeClass("loading");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from your comments, you want to control only some parts of the page that load images, right? If you are looking for just checking those images you could take a look at http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/

Easy steps:

- Include jQuery
- Include Imagesloaded script
- Fire it up like:

  ```
  $(".sly-main-slider div").hide();
  $(".sly-main-slider").addClass("loading");
  $('.sly-main-slider div').imagesLoaded()
   .done( function( instance ) {
       $(".sly-main-slider div").show();
       $(".sly-main-slider").removeClass("loading");
   });
  ```

Hope it helps

Comment: I have a question, I'm using LazyLoad XT plugin for image `src` it works when image has viewport, so is your plugin work with LazyLoad  plugin?

Comment: Fiddle doesnt run it somehow...made a Wetransfer for you.. http://we.tl/vjxkTHJJ1k
Please see if it also works for you, it works smooth here. Check console for status messages when you run this.

I never combined the 2 but why not :) I would suggest combining the first images that are shown at first into 1 div so you can use ImagesLoaded on it.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are trying to attach the `onload` event to a div. That won't work. You have attach it to the window element like this

```
$(".sly-main-slider div").hide();
$(".sly-main-slider").addClass("loading");

$(window).load(function() {
   // Handler for .load() called.
   $(".sly-main-slider div").show();
   $(".sly-main-slider").removeClass("loading");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm trying this if `.sly-main-slider div` has load, not window load. Please think about this.

Comment: @Abira You cannot attach load event to divs, It can be attached to only body and/or each external resource.

Comment: So how to achieve it? please see Means: Lists.

Comment: Simply attach it to the window like I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Start your img with an empty src, then change the src of your image async and add a callback when the img ('src') attribute has completely changed

```js
$(".sly-main-slider div img").attr('src', "#");
$(".sly-main-slider").addClass("loading");
$(".sly-main-slider div").hide();

$(".sly-main-slider div img").load(function () {
    $(".sly-main-slider div").show();
    $(".sly-main-slider").removeClass("loading");
}).attr('src', "http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/1000/");
```

```css
.loading {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    z-index: 2000;
    background: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-nfXo9GWbDtM/VOn0vr4yLMI/AAAAAAAABCA/dDNgd7_QCFo/s1600/block-loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
}

.loading:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 40px;
  content: 'Loading...';
} 
body {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='sly-main-slider'>
    <div>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/1000/1000/" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
<!--sly-main-slider end-->
```

Comment: Not possible to empty `src`

Comment: You can always do it via JS: `$(".sly-main-slider div img").attr('src', "#");` I eddited the answer to fit that.

Comment: Thank, but i mean that, i have many images, i am not able to add many image link to this jquery. :(